# Помощь с CSS выравниванием

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Встала проблема с выравниванием блоков как на картинке. Помогите пожалуйста с решением, какими способами это можно сделать? Сайт верстаю на `Bootstrap4`.

```css
.BLOCK_4_ZAGOLOVOK {
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 42px;
    color: #005aca;
    margin: 80px 0 60px 0;}
.BLOCK_4_subtitle_text{
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    line-height: 21px;}
.BLOCK_4_subtitle_text_blue{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1d487d;}
.card_priemushestva{
    padding: 20px !important;
    display: grid;}
.bottom_text{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    font-weight: lighter;}
.bottom_text_bold{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1d487d;}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="max-width: 1366px;">
        <div class="row" style="display: grid; justify-content: center;">
            <h2 class="ZAGOLOVOK_BLUE">Преимущества Smart POS</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container grid-container-block-4">
            <div class="card card-logo card_priemushestva">
                <img src="images/best-choice.png">
                <span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text">Принимайте<span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text_blue"> 10-ю </span>способами</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-logo card_priemushestva">
                <img src="images/number-1.png">
                <span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text">Подключение за<br><span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text_blue"> 1 </span>день</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="card card-logo card_priemushestva">
                <img src="images/withdraw.png">
                <span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text">Вывод средст<br> на<span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text_blue"> 3-й </span>день</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-logo card_priemushestva">
                <img src="images/percentage.png">
                <span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text">Комиссия <br> от<span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text_blue"> 0% </span></span><img src="star.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card card-logo card_priemushestva">
                <img src="images/whatsapp.png">
                <span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text">Принимайте деньги через<br><span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text_blue"> WhatsApp</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-logo card_priemushestva">
                <img src="images/credit-card.png">
                <span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text">Принимайте оплату на<br><span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text_blue"> сайте </span>или<span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text_blue"> instagram</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-logo card_priemushestva">
                <img src="images/notification.png">
                <span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text">Получайте уведомления по<br><span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text_blue"> SMS, E-mail, API</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-logo card_priemushestva">
                <img src="images/web-site.png">
                <span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text">Продающаяя страница в<br><span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text_blue"> подарок</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="card card-logo card_priemushestva">
                <img src="images/account.png" alt="">
                <span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text">Личный кабиент с <br><span class="BLOCK_4_subtitle_text_blue">удобными функциями</span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 60px"> 
            <h3 class="bottom_text"><img src="images/star1.png" alt=""> Стандартная комиссия <span class="bottom_text_bold">2,7%</span>. Сколько заплатить за сервис решать вам</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: А вы сами пробовали писать? Если да, то где ваш код. Если не пробовали, то сначала надо попробывать.

Comment: Да я писал сам, ничего не вышло, вот и решил спросить у знающих людей. Если вам нужен код, то какая часть? Я хотел чтоб подсказали какими методами можно это сделать, а не исправляли мой код)

Comment: Большая часть работы программиста это — **debag**. Ну, например саму сетку.

Comment: Вставил код с HTML, CSS вам нужен?

Comment: CSS часть тоже необходима для объективной оценки ваших попыток и соответствующей помощи вам

Comment: @doox911 добавил

Comment: @Dmitry добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо поднастроить поведение для различных экранов.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <i class="material-icons">3d_rotation</i>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <i class="material-icons">3d_rotation</i>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <i class="material-icons">3d_rotation</i>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <i class="material-icons">3d_rotation</i>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <i class="material-icons">3d_rotation</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <i class="material-icons">euro_symbol</i>
    </div>
        <div class="col">
      <i class="material-icons">euro_symbol</i>
    </div>
        <div class="col">
      <i class="material-icons">euro_symbol</i>
    </div>
        <div class="col">
      <i class="material-icons">euro_symbol</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пришлось провозиться с кодом, но все же вышло, спасибо большое)

Comment: @KRCNV если мой ответ помог вам, отметте его.